# Can you find the even number problem using with try / except?

Tags: python, list, try-catch, except

I didn't understand this thing:

```
list1 = [34,2,1,3,33,100,61,1800]

for n in list1:
    try:
        n%2 == 0
        print(n)
    except:
        pass
```

The output of the code above shows every number, but I need just even numbers.
What is my mistake?

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `try` means? Explain exactly how you expect the `print` to get skipped for odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are missing a basic idea somewhere. `try / except` is used for catching errors. In order to use this in the way you are trying to, you need to cause an error under some condition. One easy way is to `assert` the number is even. `assert n % 2 == 0`  says if `n` is not even, raise an exception. Then you can catch the exception and skip it with a `pass`

```
list1 = [34,2,1,3,33,100,61,1800]

for n in list1:
    try:
        assert n % 2 == 0 # cause an error if `n` is not even
        print(n)
    except AssertionError:
        pass
```

Comment: thank you so much, now i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a condition if

```py
list1 = [34,2,1,3,33,100,61,1800]

for n in list1:
    try:
        if n%2 == 0:
            print(n)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks for your helping mate, it was stupid question xd sorry for waste your time

Comment: How is this different than not having the `try / except` in here at all?

Comment: yes i wondered too,can you explain this

Comment: actually you don't need the try except, I just left there because I thought you would use later for other things.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. You forgot an if statement before preforming `n%2`
Second thing is, what is the point of the try and except. You don't need it.
Below is an example of your code in

**list comprehension**.

```
list1 = [34,2,1,3,33,100,61,1800]
even = [n for n in list1 if n%2 == 0]
```

**output**

```
[34, 2, 100, 1800]
```

---

**simplified code**

```
list1 = [34,2,1,3,33,100,61,1800]
even = []
for n in list1:
    if n%2 == 0:
        even.append(n)
```

**output**

```
[34, 2, 100, 1800]
```

Comment: thank you.sure i can get output that i want without using try and except but stuck in my mind this thing.